# YouTube API v3: Disliking a video in android

Tags: youtube-api

As per current documentation liking a video can be done by adding video into likes playlist.
Is there any way to dislike a video with Youtube data api v3.0.

Comment: Do you mean **unlike** - remove from *likes* list?

Comment: As per Youtube , we can also dislike a video. I am able to unlike it but i couldnt find an option for disliking the video. There is no playlist as "dislike" in youtube Data APi v3.

Comment: I see.. For me, the **playlist of disliked videos** sounds ridiculos..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to dislike (equivalent to the "thumbs down" UI option on the watch page) using the YouTube Data API v3 at this time.